# When inputting strings for multiple test cases, why does it input null character for 1st test case and how to avoid it?

Tags: string, c++11

For any given question I have to take 't' test cases each a string. I have used the following code in c++ for the same:

```
{   int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    cout<<s;
```

}

Now the problem with the above code is that it takes a null character for the first test-case. Is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

```
cin>>t;
```

reads one word(number) and leaves the carriage return on the input

you can get rid of that carriage return by

```
cin.get();
```

and then continue as you already have

good luck with your assignment !